# Recovery my Apple Id

Tags: icloud

I have forgotten my Apple Id but i know my password.And my phone need to be activated but the apple id was made mistakenly.Is there any possibility to know my Apple Id?

Answer (score 1):

On https://iforgot.apple.com, there is an option/link to follow in case you have forgotten your Apple ID. Some basic information about the account is required to proceed though.